# Rounded corner event blocks on Calendar component of NativeScript

Tags: vue.js, calendar, nativescript

Is it possible to make start/end of an event block (the green bar on picture below) rounded?

I couldn't see any option on its documentation, but I really need it.

I also want to put it in the middle of day blocks. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Is this on Android?

Comment: iOS simulator, if you ask the image.

Comment: I'm asking about your problem. You are looking for a solution on iOS, both iOS & Android.

Comment: Yes, for both of them.